# Is Count avaliable function using after def function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use count function in python but I'm not sure
can I use count in def function look likes below code?

```
def something():
....

 
print(something().count('C'))
```

I've try it but it's not working

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: I 've try it but it's not working

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'

Comment: You need to return something from your function if you want to have a returned value.

Comment: yes, it will work when you return your list, using return in def something

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

make `something` return a string, then use `count`

```py
def something():
    return "Country"

print(something().count('C'))
```